# How to install HTML 5 Boilerplate?

Tags: wordpress, html5boilerplate

I'm a total newb to Wordpress. How do I install the HTML 5 Boilerplate? I take it it's not a theme? Because I get an error uploading as there is no style.css. I don't see any documentation where it gives direction how to install. Does it go in root? Do I need to do anything to activate it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot install HTML5 boilerplate (CSS/HTML) as its not a valid WordPress theme. You need to convert it to valid theme check details here https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development or else you can use WordPress theme version from here http://html5blank.com/

Many more available check here https://www.google.co.in/#q=wordpress+html5+boilerplate